# How to invoke another function only if there is some error with a given function?

Tags: error-handling, conditionals

Assume that I have two functions, say `function1` and `function2`. I would like to execute `function2` **only if** there is some error during the execution of `function1`. So far, I have tried the below code

```
(ignore-errors (function1) (function2))
```

This executes `function2` if there is some error with `function1`, but it executes `function2` if there is no error with `function1` as well.

How to correct the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about `condition-case` in <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Handling Errors`

```el
(condition-case nil
    (function1)
  (error (function2)))
```

Comment: Thank you, but it seems not working if I do not miss something.  If `(function1)` is `(call-interactively 'ispell-word)`, `(function2)`  is `(message "hello")` and ispell default language is English and  I execute the above function on the word `Ελληνικά` since there is an error saying `Error checking word ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΆ using hunspell.exe with default dictionary` it is expected that to see `hello` but it is not the case.

Comment: At a guess, `ispell-word` is handling its own errors and *not* re-signaling it for any outer handlers to see.  In which case there simply isn't any error for you to handle, so far as your code is concerned.

Comment: Thank you, it does not solve my problem with ispell, but it literally answer the question.